# what is the Chrome version support for pattern attribute?

Tags: html, google-chrome, cross-browser, forms

I'm talking about the ability to provide a regular expression as the "pattern" attribute for an HTML textfield input. Like:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[abc]{3}"/>
```

According to http://www.chromium.org/developers/web-platform-status/forms, Chrome has supported this attribute for a while (not listed under any specific milestone). But according to http://www.coreservlets.com/html5-tutorial/input-types.html, this user tested the feature in Chrome 8 and it didn't work despite the official site claiming it should.

This feature seems to work fine in my version of Chrome, which is the latest version. However, I can't seem to find out which versions of Chrome this feature is supported in. The application I am working on is required to support Chrome versions as low as 6.0. So I wonder if someone can help me by letting me know what version of Chrome this feature was introduced?

PS: This feature definitely does not work in Safari at all. It's odd that it works in Chrome and not Safari as both are based on Webkit. This is even more evidence to me that it was probably only introduced in a fairly recent Chrome version.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what possible scenario would require you to support such old versions of Chrome?

Comment: Then there's something *seriously* wrong with your governance department. [Look at the numbers](http://www.statowl.com/web_browser_usage_by_version.php?timeframe=last_3&interval=month&chart_id=4&limit%5B%5D=chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like has might have been supported since [version 10.0](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation).

Comment: thanks! I love caniuse, and I searched the site using the search box for "pattern" but it turned up 0 results, evidently they haven't labelled that entry correctly

Comment: Well, it falls under form validation. For a more official source, [the bug page lists it as complete](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=54368&can=1&q=input%20pattern&sort=-mstone&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary)